# find files with same MD5 has within same subdirectory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find, duplicates

I have the following command:

```
find myfolder -type f -exec md5sum '{}' ';' | sort | uniq --all-repeated=separate -w 15 > dupes.txt
```

which creates a file dupes.txt which contains all images which are duplicates within the myfolder directory.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
/myfolder
 |- /1
 |- /2
 |- /..
 |- /20000
```

Problem is currently it lists same images even when they are in different sub-dirs.

What I need is that it only searches within the same sub-dirs. How do I need to adjust the commoand in order to achieve this?

Comment: ok solved: find . -type d -exec fdupes -n {} \;

Comment: add -dN for delete and no prompt.

Comment: find data-aligned -type d -exec fdupes -dN {} \;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is actually:

```
find data-aligned -type d -exec fdupes -dN {} \;
```

as written in my comments to the question.